# Serial connection does not work correctly with QPushbuttons

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, serial-port, usb

```
void CSerialController::sl_executeCommand(const QString s_command,QString&s_result){
QMutexLocker locker(mpo_mutex);
KT_Error t_error = ERROR_NONE;
QByteArray o_serialOutput;
QString s_serialAnswer = "";
char c_serialLetter = ' ';

// Port is already open

mpo_serial->clearBuffer();  // Flush and ReadAll

t_error = mpo_serial->sendStr(s_command); // 

NO_SUCCESS(t_error)
{
    Q_EMIT sg_throwError(t_error);
}

SUCCESS(t_error)
{
    while ((t_error == ERROR_NONE) && (c_serialLetter != '\n'))  // Reads Serial till newline is found 
    {
        t_error = mpo_serial->getChar(c_serialLetter);   // -> checks BytesAvailable -> if no bytes available -> waitForReadyRead(1)   <- This is in a Loop while given time is over(Timeouttime)
        o_serialOutput.append(c_serialLetter);
    }
}

NO_SUCCESS(t_error)
{
    Q_EMIT sg_throwError(t_error);
}

SUCCESS(t_error)
{
    s_serialAnswer = o_serialOutput;
    s_serialAnswer.remove("\r\n");
}

s_result = s_serialAnswer; }
```

Im working with C++ and Qt 5.5 and i cant get the serial connection to work correctly. Im using signals to connect a QPushButton with a slot in the CSerialController class which calls this function in the same class. I tried this function with a endless while-loop and it works correctly all the time. Its just not working when i use the buttons. First time i use a button it works correctly but the second time i press a button which calls this slot, the serialport only sometimes returns a value. (Writing works just not reading) I even tried changing the Thread of this class but that didnt help aswell. If you want i can post the sendStr and getChar functions aswell but like i said they work without a problem(allready used in a lot of projects)

UPDATE: I tried using the Windows API for the serial connection = problem is gone. Seems like a problem with QSerialPort usage on an old CPU (I7-870)

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Trust me i did, for about 15 hours

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? If so, are all the calls to the `mpo_serial` object made into slots called by signals or sometimes you call it directly? Then if you call the function repeatedly you just receive chars back from time to time? Did you check on the serial port if the data passes correctly or not?

Comment: The serialport passes data like it should. The object mpo_serial only has functions and no slots. The class CSerialControl only has slots because its in a different thread.

Comment: I fixed it by using the Windows Serialport instead of Qt